# How to remove spaces from mirrored fields in Sublime Text

Tags: field, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am working with snippets in Sublime Text 2/3 and would like to know if there is any way to remove spaces from mirrored fields.

### An example:

```
Variable Description = "$1";
{$1}
```

Should become the following, if the user were to type in: *Dinner Time*

```
Variable Description = "Dinner Time";
{DinnerTime}
```

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 2):

Haven't done to much with snippets before, but the substitution functionality may get you what you want. Take a look at http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html#substitutions

If I had to guess though, it would be something like  `${1/\s//g}`